# Почему число вдруг обнуляется в цикле при увеличении?

Tags: c#

Сделал цикл, в котором просто число возводится в степень.

```
int n = 10;
int a = 2;

while (n > 0)
{
    a *= a;
    Console.WriteLine(a);
    n--;
}
```

Цикл проходит 4 итерации, а после умножения 65536 на 65536, переменная обнуляется. Проверял c long. Там цикл проходил ещё одну итерации, а потом снова шли нули. Однако делал эксперимент

```
long a = long.MaxValue;

Console.WriteLine(a * a * a * a * a * a);
```

и в нём происходит ожидаемое переполнение типа без обнуления. Почему в цикле переменная обнуляется?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все зависит от того, какое значение попадет в переменную после переполнения типа `int`. В вашем случае,

> 65 536 * 65 536 = 4 294 967 296

что в битовом представлении будет равно:

> 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

Переменная типа `int` представлена 4 байтами, поэтому если отбросить пятый байт, то выходит, что в переменную будет записано значение, в котором все биты равны 0, отсюда и значение в десятичной форме равно 0.